# When I open a minimized window, I don't jump to the space it opens in

Tags: macos, spaces

I have a new hard drive with Mavericks, and I didn't have this problem on my old Mountain Lion install, so I'm sure there's some new setting somewhere I'm missing...

I have a lot of spaces open, and Google Chrome windows in all of them. I also have some Chrome windows minimized on the dock. Let's say for example that I'm in Space 1 using a Chrome window, and the minimized Chrome window was last active in Space 4. When I click the minimized window to open it, it animates up and fills the page in Space 1, where I am. Then it automatically moves the previously minimized window to Space 4. (So far, so good.) The problem? It doesn't automatically *switch* to Space 4. I'm still in Space 1, even though I clearly wanted to view the window I just un-minimized.

When I was using Mountain Lion, it automatically switched me over to Space 4. Any idea why this isn't happening now, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to System Preferences > Mission Control, and find "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"

[image]

You need to check this box.